# Can csv data be made lazy?

Tags: python, csv, clojure, lazy-evaluation

Using Python's csv module, is it possible to read an entire, large, csv file into a lazy list of lists?

I am asking this, because in Clojure there are csv parsing modules that will parse a large file and return a lazy sequence (a sequence of sequences). I'm just wondering if that's possible in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this is the default behavior, which is the very essence of reading through a csv file:

```
import csv

def lazy(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for row in r:
            yield row
```

gives you back one row at a time.

Comment: @Lattyware: Sure, I did this just to clarify/emphasize the laziness.

Comment: @Lattyware Your putting the laziness into a function created a good example, and hence a good answer. Sorry I didn't say this earlier.

Answer (score 6):

The `csv` module's `reader` is lazy by default.

It will read a line in at a time from the file, parse it to a list, and return that list.

Answer (score 2):

Python's reader or DictReader are generators. A row is produced only when the object's next() method is called.

Answer (score 1):

The csv module does load the data lazily, one row at a time.