# Efficient ways of using Python to Iterate over a CSV file and make an API Call on each row

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv

I created a script which can read a csv file and trigger an api call on each row.  It works, but my concern is if I will run into memory issues if the file is over 1M rows.

```
import json
import requests
import csv
import time

"""

PURPOSE:
    This is a script designed to: 
        1. read through a CSV file 
        2. loop through each row of the CSV file
        3. build and trigger an API Request to the registerDeviceToken endpoint
        using the contents of each row of the CSV File
INSTRUCTIONS:
    1. Create a CSV file with columns in the following order (left to right):
        1. email
        2. applicationName (i.e. your bundle ID or package name)
        3. platform (i.e. APNS, APNS_SANDBOX, GCM)
        4. token (i.e. device token)
    2. Save CSV file and make note of the full 'filepath'
    3. Define the required constant variables below
    4. Run python script

Note: If your CSV files does not contain column headings, then set 
contains_headers to 'False'        
"""


# Define constant variables
api_endpoint = '<Insert API Endpoint>'

# Update per user specifications
file_location = '/Users/bob/Development/Python/token.csv' # Add location of CSV File
api_key = '<insert API Key: Type server-side' # Add your API Key
contains_headers = True # Set to True is file contains column headers


def main():
    # Open and read CSV File
    with open(r'%s' % (file_location)) as x:
        reader = csv.reader(x)
        if contains_headers == True:
            next(reader)  # Skip the first row if file contains column headers
        counter = 0 # This counter is used to monitor Rate Limit
        
        # Loop through each 
        for row in reader:
            
            jsonBody = {}
            device = {}
            # Create JSON body for API Request
            device['applicationName'] = row[1]
            device['platform'] = row[2]
            device['token'] = row[3]
            device['dataFields'] = {'endpointEnabled': True}
            jsonBody['email'] = row[0]
            jsonBody['device'] = device
            
            # Create API Request
            destinationHeaders = {
                'api_key': api_key,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            r = requests.post(api_endpoint, headers=destinationHeaders, json=jsonBody)
            print(r)
            data = json.loads(r.text)
            
            # Print Successes/Errors to console 
            msg = 'user %s token %s' % (row[0],row[3])
            if r.status_code == 200:
                try:
                    msg = 'Success - %s. %s' % (msg, data['msg'])
                except Exception:
                    continue
            else:
                msg = 'Failure - %s. Code: %s, Details: %s' % (msg, r.status_code, data['msg'])
            print(msg)
            # Add delay to avoid rate limit
            counter = counter + 1
            if counter == 400:
                time.sleep(2)
                counter = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've read about using Pandas with chunking as an option, but using the Dataframe is not intuitive to me, and I can't figure out how to parse through each row of the chunk, like I do in the example above.  A few questions:

1. Will what I currently have run into any memory issues if the file is over a million rows?  Each CSV should only have 4 columns, if that helps.
2. Is Pandas chunking going to be more efficient? If so, how can I iterate over each row of the 'csv chunk' to build my API request like in the example above?

In my pathetic attempt to chunk the file, the result of printing the 'row' in this code:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_location, chunksize=chunk_size):
        for row in chunk:
            print(row)
```

returns

```
email
device
applicationName
platform
token
```

So I am super confused.  Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: I don't think you will have a problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109524/can-csv-data-be-made-lazy . csv reader will iterate over the rows as opposed to read all into mem.

Comment: also side note I would re-arrange `data = json.loads(r.text)` to after you check the status code. As I am not even sure what you are checking in that `try/except` block with a successful post.

Comment: great point on the try/except, thank you @Chinny84

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at python generators. Generators are kind of iterators that do not store all the values in memory

```py
def read_file_generator(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as csv_file:
        for row in csv_file:
            yield row


def main():
    for row in read_file_generator("my_file.csv"):
        print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
``
```